# Getting the bottom line of a RichTextBox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB that requires the last line of a text box. Is there a way I can get the last line as a string? An example:

RichTextBox contents:

Some
random
text

The program would return the string "text"

Comment: *What have you tried?*

Comment: Well, my program is a terminal emulator. I have it set to this:`For Each Command As String In RichTextBox1.Lines` The problem is, it process all of the lines not just the last one.

Comment: Simply `richTextBox1.Lines.Last()`.

Comment: Hmmm. `RichTextBox1.Lines.Last` doesn't quite work. Any way of getting second to last?

Comment: Oop! Never mind. I got it to work :)

Comment: @JordanFitz, please post your answer. I am in need of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
Dim lines As String() = myRichTextbox.Text.Split(New Char() {"\n"c})

String lastLine = lines(UBound(lines))
```

So `Split()` returns an array of string, where each string is a line in your TextBox.
And `UBound()` returns the last index of that array, in order to get the last line of your Textbox.

Or, as I just red, you can use `myRichTextBox.Lines` instead of `` ` myRichTextbox.Text.Split(...) ``:

```
String lastLine = myRichTextBox.Lines(UBound(myRichTextBox.Lines))
```